# merge dataframe columns with same name BUT without sorting the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the column names:

```
'01 2017' '02 2017' ...... '12 2017' '01 2018' '01 2018' ....
```

so you can see there is a repeat of 01 2018 and 01 2018 for two columns. I would like to sum the columns without rearranging the columns.

I have this code currently:

```
df.groupby(lambda x:x, axis=1).sum()
```

However, the ouput is:

```
'01 2017' '01 2018' ... '12 2017' '12 2018'
```

This sorts it by the first 2 digits and messes up the arrangement.

Comment: Please take a moment to take a look at the advice at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples and the instructions it has there as to tips on making an answerable question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `reindex`, using @piRSquared setup modified:

Use df.columns.unique true a list of unique column names in the current order, then use reindex with axis=1 to order the columns after the groupby with sum.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(10, size=(6, 5)),
    columns='1 2017|2 2017|1 2018|2 2018|2 2018'.split('|')
)
df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).sum().reindex(df.columns.unique(), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   1 2017  2 2017  1 2018  2 2018
0       9       2       4      15
1       5       0       0      10
2       1       8       5      10
3       1       1       9       8
4       9       0       0       0
5       6       1       4       5
```

Answer (score 2):

By using the data from Pir , slightly change it

*`Data input`*

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 4)),
    columns='1 2017|2 2017|1 2018|1 2018'.split('|')
)
df
Out[346]: 
   1 2017  2 2017  1 2018  1 2018
0       0       2       7       3
1       8       7       0       6
2       8       6       0       2
3       0       4       9       7
4       3       2       4       3
```

---

*`solution`*

```
df.sum(level=0,axis=1) # using `sum`
Out[347]: 
   1 2017  2 2017  1 2018
0       0       2      10
1       8       7       6
2       8       6       2
3       0       4      16
4       3       2       7
```

Comment: I like your solution better. :) +1  "Myopic Scott" they call me.

Comment: @ScottBoston ha, that made me lol.  I'm guilty as well.  I missed the duplicate columns and all that (-:

Comment: Deleting my answer.  Grab setup for your guy's answers.